# Is there a technology similar to Docker Containers for Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, docker, containers, windows-server-2016

Docker Containers (which is basically application isolation, afaik) look handy but they are only for Linux.  Even "Docker Container for Windows" basically just installs a Linux VM into VirtualBox on Windows.

So is there such a thing as a Docker Container like technology for Windows Server?

Comment: [Parallels Containers for Windows](http://sp.parallels.com/products/parallels-containers-windows/) comes close but can be pricey.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not yet, no - it's [been announced](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/15/new-windows-server-containers-and-azure-support-for-docker/) as a feature of the next version of Windows Server (Windows Server 2016).

Answer (score 2):

Containers are available in [Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 3](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn765472.aspx).

Comment: How is this a different answer than the one that's already been here for a year?

Comment: @MDMarra I thought it was significant that, beyond the announcement, you can [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview) and use Windows Containers today.

Answer (score 2):

To complete answer, starting Windows Server 2016 (Technical Preview 3 and >) you are able to create and run Windows based containers. Docker Engine has been implemented in Windows Server 2016 as well as Docker CLI. So you can manage Linux and Windows containers with the same tool (Docker CLI...). For sysadmin who prefer PowerShell, it's also possible to manage Windows Containers using PowerShell cmdlets. Just remember that Linux containers are running on top of a Linux OS (Docker Host) and Windows containers on top of a Windows Server OS (Docker host).

Additional informations

- Introducing the Technical Preview of Docker Engine for Windows Server 2016
  http://blog.docker.com/2015/08/tp-docker-engine-windows-server-2016/
- Windows Containers
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome

Regards

Stanislas